# NodeJS - how to access scoped variables from eventListener

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, zeromq

I'm very new to `NodeJS` and web development.
I'm using an express web server and the requester.on is a `ZMQ listener`.

How can I access the respective res object of the respective app.post() methods ? I tried it by moving the requester.on-listener into any app.post methods but it caused bad side effects.

```
app.post("/first", function (req, res) {
    var reqStringFirst
    requester.send(reqString);
    //the app gets a response immediately after the send() call
});

app.post("/second", function (req, res) {
    var reqStringSecond
    requester.send(reqString);
    //the app gets a response immediately after the send() call
});

requester.on("message", function (reply) {
    var replyJSON = new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(reply);

    // and here I want to use the respective res 
    // object to render different pages depending on the replyJSON content. 

    //like this line:
    res.render("pages/serviceDetails", {replyJSON});
});
```

kindest regards

Comment: why dont you use req.on

Comment: inside of post method and also you can use body parser which is make your incoming values to json in req.body object in post

Comment: this is simple example working with zmq and socket 
https://gist.github.com/ChuckJHardy/6743683

Comment: Thanks for ur response. I don't want to use it inside the post method because it makes trouble and the not just the correct listener is called. Wenn I call listener A, then another listener B both of them are called. Thats are the sideeffects i mentioned

Comment: And thanks for the zmq example but theres the major difference that i want to do different operations in a listener and thats why I need to access a scoped variable :/

Comment: Any post call would generate a new listener which ends which the following message: "(node:24706) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 message listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
" And all of them will be called each time